# Como puedo hacer un update de mi usuario con mi Api de Construida en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, passport

estoy construyendo una api para luego integrarla a ionic.. Hasta ahora lo que hice fue la parte de autenticacion y perfil de usuario que funciona bien.. ahora lo que quiero hacer es poder actualizar mi usuario pero no se porque razon en mi request no recibo nada... estoy haciendo mis pruebas con postman
mi metodo update

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->name = $request->get('name');
        $user->email = $request->get('email');
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password');
        $user->save();
        return response()->json(compact('user'), 200);
    }
```

esto me da un error ya que me dice que name no puede ser nulo, entonces lo que hice fue comentar mi codigo y returnar mi request asi `return response()->json(compact('request'), 200);` y el resultado que arrojo fue esto

```
{
"request": {
    "attributes": {},
    "request": {},
    "query": {},
    "server": {},
    "files": {},
    "cookies": {},
    "headers": {}
}
```

}

que como veran esta completamente vacio.
[image: mi postman]

Comment: Prueba `return $request->all();`, si te devuelve un array vacío, posiblemente no estén saliendo los datos desde potman.

Comment: Recibo los datos pero en este formato cuando le aplique el `$request->all()`, me salio esto ` "------WebKitFormBoundarybCN5cVA0EaBjXV80\r\nContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name": "\"name\"\r\n\r\nWalter Hernan Chaparro\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarybCN5cVA0EaBjXV80\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\nhernachaparro@gmail.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarybCN5cVA0EaBjXV80\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\nleo12345\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarybCN5cVA0EaBjXV80--"`

Comment: se ve un poco inentendible pero se puede ver que recibio los datos que envie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo lo siguiente:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $user->name = $request->has('name') ? $request->get('name') : $user->name;
    $user->email = $request->has('email') ? $request->get('email') : $user->email;
    $user->password = $request->has('password') ? bcrypt($request->get('password')) : $user->password;
    $user->save();

    return response()->json($user, 200);
}
```

Como puedes ver, primero se comprueba si la request trae los campos, en caso de no tenerlos (porque el usuario no los haya enviado, debido a que **solamente** quiera cambiar su nombre por ejemplo), entonces actualizas los campos que el usuario está solicitando y los demás quedan igual.

**OPCIONAL**

Para mostrar el usuario actualizado, podrías crear un método show

```
public function show($id){
    $user = User::show($id)
    ->withTrashed()
   ->first();

    return response()->json($user, 200);
}
```

Y al final de tu método update cambiar el

`return response()->json($user, 200);`

por

`return $this->show($id);`.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Esta bien el metodo update que me pasaste pero mi problema es que no estoy recibiendo el request... y al no recibir pues simplemente no va a realizar ningun cambio

Comment: que headers le envias a la request? Veo que tienes 3 en postman

Comment: Gracias a tu pregunta enconte mi problema, estaba enviando `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` y por eso no me funcionaba... gracias por la ayuda